# Taking control over audio

Tags: android, audio

I have an app that streams audio. When the user starts to stream I need to own the audio: If the media player or radio is running I need it to be stopped.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You must gain focus with the [Audio manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html). Notably use `requestAudioFocus()`